# displaying excel sheet in web application and providing edit feature on the fly

Tags: excel, jsp, contenteditable

I do not have the option of using iFrame for displaying excel sheet in web app as the excel sheet is fetched from the database and differs for each person logged in. Hence the excel sheet can neither be uploaded to onedrive or google drive. Oh and also its a JSP Servlets web app so am a bit tied there as well.

While I saw there are various plugins available, my head has been spinning from the google results , the best I could think of ..was to create and editable table out of the excel sheet.

To elaborate my requirement, this is the flow I want to achieve, implementation is big question mark!!

1. Read excel sheet from DB (this has already been uploaded by user in another form)
2. Allow user to view and edit this sheet on another form
3. Submit button on 2nd form picks the changed sheet data as a binary stream and invokes REST API which then does something with this sheet.

I saw Jexcel as an option but do not know how to import excel data into it, I guess any other good jquery plugin could also help, only am short of time in researching

Please help!!!

Answer (score 0):

jExcel can easily load data from csv file or json

if you spreadsheet is in csv format, it can be loaded into the jExcel like this:

```
<div id='my-spreadsheet'></div>

<script>
jexcel(document.getElementById('my-spreadsheet'), {
    csv:'demo.csv',
    csvHeaders:true
});
</script>
```

the first line in your csv becomes the column header, and the data displayed in the grid.

and when you save the changes, you can get the header and data by calling the two APIs:

```
getHeaders()
getData()
```

and your REST API can handle the data whatever you want to do with it.

Comment: I have explored this option. but facing difficulty in content conversion as Excel sheet doesnt have data in continuous rows. Opted for an editable HTML table instead with calculation by Jquery